# Transit without visa through Sydney Airport when changing carriers

Tags: visas, transit, australia

I am transiting through Sydney Airport but am changing carriers to my next destination in Thailand, so I have to retrieve my bags and re check-in.

Does transit without visa still apply?

Comment: Changing air carriers does not necessarily mean that you must transfer your bags yourself. Did you buy a single ticket? On which airlines?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you can't use transit without visa if you need to leave the transit lounge for any reason. [DIBP](https://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia):

> Travellers must:
>
> - not need to leave the airport transit lounge except to continue their journey.